# Windows API - IOCTL_CHANGER_GET_PRODUCT_DATA always returning ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER

Tags: c, windows, winapi, deviceiocontrol

I am the author of a communication library which needs to be able to communicate with serial devices and USB devices, through libusb and the native driver which corresponds to our case (CESG502, made by CASIO). Serial and libusb communication are both managed, I now want to integrate the use of CESG502 (the driver made for what we want).

The main problem comes from this driver : instead of managing the buffering the same way serial drivers do (if more data is received, it is stored until the user asks it), it expects the developer to provide a bigger buffer than data is received. This leads to two incompatible uses of `ReadFile`, where I have to only put the number of bytes I want to actually receive (serial, otherwise it just waits for the rest which will never come) or the size of the buffer (CESG502; if I don't do this, the driver returns a `ERROR_GEN_FAILURE`).

The driver is proprietary, so I cannot correct it. Because of the design of my library, I need to identify if the driver is CESG502 or not in order to work in most cases the library is made to work in. I have looked and found [IOCTL_CHANGER_GET_PRODUCT_DATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363395(v=vs.85).aspx), which looks like could bring the information I'm looking for. So I tried to use it [here](https://github.com/cakeisalie5/libp7/blob/7c218985711e1f55f1b0812ccdd205ac5f569ff9/src/stream/windows.c#L400):

```
/* get product data */
CHANGER_PRODUCT_DATA ProductData; DWORD ReturnedBytes = 0;
DWORD wsuccess = DeviceIoControl(fhandle, IOCTL_CHANGER_GET_PRODUCT_DATA,
    NULL, 0, &ProductData, sizeof(CHANGER_PRODUCT_DATA),
    &ReturnedBytes, 0);
if (wsuccess) logr_info("SUCCESS!");
else logr_info("Error #0x%08lx occurred", GetLastError());
```

Unfortunately, I continuously receive the 0x57 (`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`) error, which also occurs with serial devices. I am following what the page said, I have tried plenty of things (setting `ReturnedBytes` to `sizeof(CHANGER_PRODUCT_DATA)`, initializing `ProductData`, reading the data anyway, ...) and I have found out where this error comes from...

Thanks in advance if you know how to solve this :)

Comment: `IOCTL_CHANGER...` is an I/O control code for tape changer devices, the robots inside tape libraries that transfer the tapes from the shelves into the actual tape readers and back.  From your description, you're not dealing with a tape changer device, so the control code isn't applicable.

Comment: Oh, geez, I see! Do you know what I could use then? :o

Comment: I'm not sure.  Perhaps [`IOCTL_GET_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff542856(v=vs.85).aspx) would work?

Comment: Well, the fact is, my objective is not to identify the device, but the driver (another driver could take care of this device)... :s

Comment: Probably the Setup API or the Configuration Manager API then.  But I'm not personally familiar enough with them to give any specific advice.  Perhaps someone else will be able to help.